# can I use 'let' inside a 'cond' in a Scheme function?

Tags: scheme

newbie to Scheme, trying to write a function that takes a list, and three items as input, replaces item1 with item2, uses `let` to name it temporarily, then reverses this temp list and adds item3 to its end.

This is just for tinkering with Scheme and not a homework problem. Any advice is appreciated:

I have tried using `let*` without success, and removed `cond` and still in vain.

```
(define (itemreplacer item1 item2 item3 leest)
 (cond ( 
        (eq? (car leest) item1)
        (cons item2 (cdr leest)))
        (else
        (let
          (
           (templist (cons item1 (itemreplacer (cdr (leest))))))
          (reverse (cons item3 templist))))))
```

It works upto the point where the item2 replaces item1, and only shows this as output. Somehow, the `reverse` line does not run.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and expected output for your code.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your excellent reply! The input is the same as the code above, and the expected output is as described:  a list of any size is taken as input, along with three items. The function searches the list, if any element matches item1, it replaces it with item2, then reverses the list and adds item3 to its end.

Comment: That still doesn’t answer my question. By input I mean: post the actual list and items you’re passing as parameters. By output I mean, post the actual list you expect as a result. Don’t explain it in words, add a real example please.

Comment: ok here you are:   list is: ```(define somelist '(1 2 4 6 7 8 9 10))```  and the input args are: ```(itemreplacer somelist 6 5 3)```                                  Expected output:  ```'(10 9 8 7 5 4 2 1 3)```.                                                 So 6 was replaced by 5, and the list was reversed, and a 3 was added to its end. Thanks for your patience! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `let` expression is fine, that's not the problem. There are more serious issues with the code:

- You forgot to write a base case for the recursion
- It's preferred to use `equal?` for comparisons (it's more general)
- Do not surround a value with brackets, unless it's a procedure you want to invoke, code like this will fail: `(leest)`
- You're not providing the correct amount of parameters when recursively calling `itemreplacer`
- The general idea of your solution isn't right. What we should use here is a helper procedure (or alternatively, a named `let`), to accumulate the partial results up until the point where we find `item1`

Because of the last item, I had to rewrite the logic of the procedure to meet the requirements:

```
(define (itemreplacer leest item1 item2 item3)
  (replacer-helper leest item1 item2 item3 '()))

(define (replacer-helper leest item1 item2 item3 acc)
  (cond ((null? leest) (reverse acc))
        ((equal? (car leest) item1)
         (append (reverse (cdr leest)) (cons item2 acc) (list item3)))
        (else
         (replacer-helper (cdr leest) item1 item2 item3 (cons (car leest) acc)))))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(itemreplacer '(1 2 4 6 7 8 9 10) 6 5 3)
=> '(10 9 8 7 5 4 2 1 3)
```

The behavior for the case when `item1` was not found is unspecified, so I'll just return the original input:

```
(itemreplacer '(1 2 4 6 7 8 9 10) 13 5 3)
=> '(1 2 4 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Comment: Thanks! You are indeed a great teacher. I should remind myself not to code when sleepy. :)

Comment: No problem, it was a pleasure. Thank you for your kind words :)